# acts as tree in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-tree

I am facing problem with acts_as_tree_on_steroids with rails 3.
Is there any plugin which will help in rails 3 same as acts as tree

app/controllers/question_attributes_controller.rb:9:in `index'

Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (0.8ms)
Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (6.5ms)
Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout
for a.descendants

Answer (score 0):

use this instead http://rubygems.org/gems/acts_as_tree_rails3